# Is there a standard way of storing data for C++ applications?

Tags: c++, json

In the Java and JavaScript world json files are a standard way of storing complex data objects in files. Does C++ have its own standards in this matter too?

Comment: I guess I did not choose my words correctly. I am sure that this is not tied down in THE STANDARD. I was just asking about common practice.

Answer (score 3):

While I would disagree that storing JSON files is a "standard way" (esp. for Java), there are many different ways to achieve that in any language. It totally depends on your actual use case. You can write primitive values to files, key/value pairs of some sort, XML, JSON, YAML, write to a Database, send data to web services, ...

No, there is no standard way for generically storing data to files.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You could use static data (and have its constructor called, conceptually before `main` in an *unspecified* order).

You could also have a big literal string in your file -the [raw string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#New_string_literals)
 feature of C++11 is handy- and have some code (e.g. a constructor which would accept a string encoded in JSON form) parse it.

Answer (score 0):

They are just one way of storing data. Not "standard".

XML is another for example. All of these are available in C++ along with others